# Why SOAP Request obj data going to Server from Client as Null in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, soap-client

I am trying to consuming SOAP Webservices in SpringBoot maven project. SO i have generated classes using wsdl. I am trying to call the server and the client is able to hit server but the request data is going to the server as null.

I am not getting why the request data is going to the server as null. please find the my code as below:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = Constants.NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "StatementsList")
    @ResponsePayload
    public StatementsListResponse statementsListRequest(@RequestPayload StatementsList request) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Enters into StatementsList()");

     //here is the Client call
        WSClient client = new WSClient();
        response = client.statementsListService(request.getXMLRequest());

        return response;
    }


@Component
public class WSClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport{

   private ServicesSoapStub soapStub = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws ServiceException {
        // will get invoked after all injections


        ServicesLocator sLocator = new ServicesLocator();
        ServicesSoapStub stub = (ServicesSoapStub) sLocator.getServicesSoap();

        soapStub = stub;
    }

  public  StatementsListResponse statementsListService(StatementsListRequest request)
            throws RemoteException, ServiceException {

            //Here i am able to print the request obj data and able to see the data as well.
        System.out.println("Enters into WSClient :: statementsListService()"); 


        return soapStub.statementsList(request);

    }
}
```

SOAP UI Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prim="http://***/Services">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <prim:StatementsList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <prim:XMLRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Header>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:MessageID>1</prim:MessageID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:CorrelationID>1</prim:CorrelationID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:SystemID>1</prim:SystemID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:RequestorID>1</prim:RequestorID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prim:InstitutionID>1</prim:InstitutionID>
            </prim:Header>
            <prim:Reference>A</prim:Reference>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <prim:Number>40000</prim:Number>
         </prim:XMLRequest>
      </prim:StatementsList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The above operation testing by using SOAP UI. and i am able to print the data of request obj which has passed from SOAP UI in above request obj.

Can anyone please suggest why the request is going to the server as null.Is there any thing am doing worng here.Please suggest on this.

Comment: I would expect `NullPointerException` to happen with your current code.

Comment: In Client side there is no issues but in sever side they are getting all request values as null i.e issue Thanks.@M. Deinum

Comment: hen you are sending an empty request. Also if you don't get a `NullPointerException` the code you posted here isn't the code you are actually using.

Comment: I am working at client side and before calling " return soapStub.statementsList(request);" this and able to see the request data by printing on console(soap ui data) but the request values are getting by null at server end. Thanks @M. Deinum

Comment: As stated the code you posted here will result in a `NullPointerException`. So you either aren't using this code or the code think you are using isn't the code being used. The `NullPointerException` comes from the fact you are doing `new WsClient()` which creates a new instance which will always have `null` for the `soapStub` as the `init` method doesn't get called. I also do't understand why you are extending `WebServiceGatewaySupport` as you aren't using that.

Comment: As i am not getting null Pointer exception and able to call the server and getting the response from server as well. But why null values are going to server i.e i am trying get help from you peoples.  As the way i am doing above is correct right? @M. Deinum

Comment: And I'm telling you then this isn't the code you are actually using (but some interpreted code you posted here). Without the actual code we cannot really help you. If the values are there, as you are stating, then sending them should simply work. If that isn't the case your stub isn't doing what you expect it to do.